# intento lanzar echo *PHP* pero me imprime en consola *javascript*

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

Estoy intentando lanzar un echo que imprima en pantalla unos valores los cuales estoy enviando por medio de **Js/Ajax** a mi controlador. Pero al momento de generar el

> echo json_encode($post);

dentro de mi controlador **php** para que muestre los valores que le envié me los imprime por medio de la consola del navegador.

En mi controlador tengo este arreglo y el echo en el cual deseo imprimir:

```
$post = [
            'eventoId'  => $eventoId,
            'cantidad'  => $cantidad,
            'usuarioId' => $usuarioId,
            'ubicacion' => $ubicacion,
            'valor'     => $valor,
              ];

echo json_encode($post);
```

actualmente mi archivo js no está recibiendo nada dentro de la función *.done* ya que tengo entendido que si recibe un Json contaminado este lanzará un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

así funciona AJAX

1.- Tú mandas una peticion por AJAX

2.- El servidor recibe la petición y devuelve una respuesta

3.- Recibes la respuesta en el callback de tu funcion

4.- Esos datos recibidos los trabajas para imprimirlos en tu documento

```
$.ajax({
    //parametros
}).done(function(data){
    $('div').text(data) // o un loop para imprimir elemento por elemento. Etc.
})
```

de hecho no deberías poner

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

si no

```
return json_encode($result);
```

por que las funciones no deben imprimir datos sino retornarlos.

Comment: en ese caso no es posible que el imprima el valor dentro del php por pantalla para efectos de prueba mientras retorno un valor string único al JS por medio de un Json?
dentro de mi código finalmente este echo es solo para efectos de confirmar que recibo los datos correctos, y a mi JS le envío un "1" o "2" para confirmar lo sucedido dentro de mi controlador.

Comment: El resultado es el mismo en ambos casos, si haces echo o return te devolverá los valores impresos en pantalla, es solo buena practica usar return en lugar de echo. En ambos casos tendrás que ver dichos valores en la consola de depuración y trabajar con ellos por medio de JS

Comment: pues he realizado el ejercicio y retornado el valor por medio de un json_encode. . .he intentado imprimir por pantalla por medio de un 

`document.write(data);`

aunque me sigue imprimiendo por consola, lo que necesito es imprimir por pantalla para efectos de prueba, ya que es lo que me están requiriendo.

Comment: Solo tienes que hacer un text en tu elemento, te dejo un ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/n7rzsxa4/

Comment: Tambien es falso que no puedas retornar un json contaminado, cualquier respuesta puede regresar el servidor incluso html.

Comment: vale, me ha sucedido que en ocasiones cuando dejo alguna linea de código comentada o si realizo un echo en alguna función a la que se le enviará algún valor por *_JSON_ esté me muestra un error por consola **unexpected json token**... y se decía que es porque el json se contamina al momento de retornar por el ajax.

Comment: Ya pero es que lo transformas con la funcion json_encode() en ese caso sí te da error, pero si imprimes la data como está sin encodearla para hacer debug  no tendrás problema. :)